# jQuery Minimum Character Counter for Codeigniter Textarea

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, character, counter

I'm struggling to get a minimum character counter to work with CI / jQuery. I want to be able to prevent form submission and display an alert if the user has entered too few chars.  The form just submits as normal using the code:

```
function checktextarea(minLength) {

  var textarea = jQuery('#field').value.length;
     if(textarea < minLength) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('You need to enter at least ' + minLength ' + characters');
        return false;
     }
};
```

And in CI I have:

```
<?php $attributes = array ('onsubmit' => 'checktextarea(15)'); ?>
<?php echo form_open('controller/function', $attributes); ?>

// I know this is standard HTML
  <textarea name="content" class="textarea_css" rows="10" cols="73" id="field"></textarea>

<?php echo form_submit('send', 'Submit Your Textarea'); ?>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: Are you getting any errors in your browser console? http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a reference to an `e` var, which isn't in the scope of your function. I'm assuming you're trying to cancel an event, but you should do that in your parent function.

The line `e.preventDefault();` causes compile errors.

Next, you are accessing the value of the text area improperly, try `jQuery('#field').val().length;`.

Finally, the line `alert('You need to enter at least ' + minLength ' + characters');` is malformed, it should read `alert('You need to enter at least ' + minLength  + ' characters');`

Added a fiddle, just for fun and proof: http://jsfiddle.net/TSbK8/7/

Comment: Ultimately with Codeigniter I had to use: <?php echo form_submit('send', 'Submit', 'onclick = "return checkTextArea(50)"'); ?>

Answer (score 0):

You're jQuery statement getting the length isn't quite right. Instead of `var textarea = jQuery('#field').value.length;` try `var textarea = jQuery('#field').val().length;`.

Comment: I had tried that jQuery variation instead of Javascript but it doesn't make any difference :-(

Comment: Also, the `onsubmit` function needs to have `return` in it. Try editing the `checktextarea(15)` to be `return checktextarea(15)`.